# Choice with sequences - got an unexpected keyword argument while using Zeep

Tags: python, xml, soap, zeep

I encountered the following problem while using zeep library. My XSD has the following XML structure:

```
<xs:complexType name="cofPaymentType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="paymentInstrument" type="tns:paymentInstrument"/>
                <xs:element name="payment" type="tns:paymentType"/>
                <xs:element name="cvvCode" type="tns:cvvCodeType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="encryptedData" type="tns:encryptedDataType"/>
                <xs:element name="payment" type="tns:paymentType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="tdsAuthResult" type="tns:tdsAuthResult" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'am passing among others the following data:

```
data = {"encryptedData": {"field1": "foo", "field2":  "bar"}, "payment": payment}
response = client.service.payment(**data)
```

The response what I receive:

```
{http://www.example.pl/integration/virtual/transaction/v1}cofPaymentType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encryptedData'. Signature: `({paymentInstrument: {http://www.example.pl/integration/virtual/transaction/v1}paymentInstrument, payment: {http://www.example.pl/integration/virtual/transaction/v1}paymentType, cvvCode: {http://www.example.pl/integration/virtual/transaction/v1}cvvCodeType} | {encryptedData: {http://www.example.pl/integration/virtual/transaction/v1}encryptedDataType, payment: {http://www.example.pl/integration/virtual/transaction/v1}paymentType}), tdsAuthResult: {http://www.example.pl/integration/virtual/transaction/v1}tdsAuthResult`"}
```

But the field encryptedData occurs in the second choice. It's look like that only first choice is chosen. Am I right? How can I get second choice?

I've also tried creat request using factory = client.type_factory('ns0') but the result is the same. It doesn't see elements from second choice.

Generally zeep has problem with convert request to XML structure. So I cannot even generate: https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/client.html#creating-the-raw-xml-documents because of "got an unexpected keyword" described above.

Comment: Ok, I've resolved my problem. I've changed way of creating factory.
When I've used:

`cof_payment = factory.cofPaymentType(encryptedData=encrypted_data, payment = payment)`

factory was making "call" and validating with XSD.

So I've made a change to:


`cof_payment = factory.cofPaymentType()
cof_payment.encryptedData = encrypted_data
cof_payment.payment = payment`